# how to change the background color of the holder of an image using jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

I am using a jQuery.cycle.all.js for my images on my site. I want to change the background of the image as the images changes/cycles. So clearly I want to change the background of the div with the id flash. How to do that, any idea?

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nixiechen/3ndpfnys/

Here is the javascript:

```
$('.holder').cycle({
    timeout:2000        
});

/*pause-play buttons*/
$('.pause').on('click',function() {         
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    $('.play').addClass('on');
    $('.holder').cycle('pause'); 
});
$('.play').on('click',function() {          
    $(this).removeClass('on');      
    $('.pause').addClass('on');     
    $('.holder').cycle('resume'); 
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="flash">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="btns">
            <a href="#" class="play" id="">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#" class="pause on" id="">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="holder">
            <img src="../images/01.jpg" alt="image"/>
            <img src="../images/02.jpg" alt="image"/>
            <img src="../images/03.jpg" alt="image"/>
            <img src="../images/04.jpg" alt="image"/>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
#flash { overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 350px; background: #0a0f2c; }
#flash .wrapper { position: relative; height: 350px; z-index: 1; }
#flash .btns { position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 175px; left: 5px; z-index: 10000; }
#flash .btns a { float: left; width: 21px; height: 21px; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px; text-decoration: none; }
#flash .btns a.play { display: block; background: url(../images/btn/btn_play_off.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
#flash .btns a.play.on { background: url(../images/btn/btn_play_on.png) no-repeat; }
#flash .btns a.pause { background: url(../images/btn/btn_pause_off.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
#flash .btns a.pause.on { background: url(../images/btn/btn_pause_on.png) no-repeat; }
#flash .holder { position: absolute; left: -150px; }
#flash .blue { background: #0a0f2c; }
#flash .brown { background: #3b1e16; }
#flash .black { background: #000; }
```

updated the jsfiddle link

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: Please, update your jsfiddle, It does not work.

Comment: @alireza safian http://jsfiddle.net/nixiechen/3ndpfnys/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `background-color` to the `#flash` in `cycle before function`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ndpfnys/2/)

```
var color = 154235;
$('.holder').cycle({
    timeout: 2000,
    before: function (currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {
        $('#flash').css({
            'background-color': '#' + color
        });
        color += 20;
    }
});
```

Comment: that would work. but the background color would be match with what the image has. like if the image is black then the background is black. if the image is pink then the background would be pink too.

Comment: One option is html data attributes. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3ndpfnys/4/)

Comment: There are several plugin which can detect the image color.